# Cross domain AJAX in plain html file

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I have an app in plain html file (no server). How do I do cross domain requests (from javascript)?

Browser reports error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load '*'. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I tried the following, but no dice.

```
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*"/>
```

Comment: Are you in charge of the domain from which you're attempting to fetch resources? Or does someone else control it?

Comment: @JeremiahMegel I'm in charge of it

Comment: The cross domain server on which you are firing the request should have crosa domain requests enabled on its end

Comment: You probably want to use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43434350/edit to edit/update the question to add a code snippet to show what JavaScript code you already tried which is causing that message to be emitted. You should also indicate whether or not you control the server you're sending the request to, and if not, then include the URL for the request you're trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) *HTTP* header (not an HTML `<meta>` tag) on the *target* resource. Set it to either `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: source-domain.example.com` to allow only your source domain access to it or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to allow any domain access. The first is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

`meta http-equiv` is not equivalent to an HTTP header. You must make a request to an HTTP server, and it must respond with *real* HTTP headers.